# How can I create a new XML doc based on my existing one and rename some elements?

Tags: php, xml

I need to create an XML document for a website service that shows products from many e-shops through their search engine.

When I talked with the development team they said me that I need to have an XML that follows their structure and system.

My question is how can I create a new eshopNEW.xml based on my eshop.xml BUT change the names of some of the elements to meet their structure requirements? For example suppose that I need to change the `item` to `product`, `title` to `name` and add into it an attribute `type="game"`.

I have pasted a simple XML so that I will understand the process of creating a new document and the transformation of the names easier.

Thank you for your answers.

```
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good use case for [XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/).

E.g. put in an identity template to pass elements through unchanged by default:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then add specific templates for elements whose names you need to change:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <product>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <name>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hmm it is not that hard to make it (if you see the solution of course). Now I guess I have to call this xslt, the xml and output the result right ? Please let me know what does the first <xsl...></xsl> does?

Comment: I just saw the commenting, thank you for that. How can I add an attribute though ?

Comment: @Sampas: you can add attributes either with a literal result element, e.g. `<product foo="bar">`, or using `<xsl:attribute name="foo">bar</xsl:attribute>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes

Comment: XSLT is definitely the right tool for this job. Like any powerful technology, however, it does have a bit of a learning curve. Don't expect to master it in ten minutes.